# Is there a possibility for the ngx-bootstrap typeahead to still give suggestions for more values after some values already picked?

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

When having for instance an array of possible values `['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']`, applying typeahead directive on an input text field and typing *'r'* it would give suggestions of **red** and **green**. Let's say you picked **red** and it got entered to the input. Is it possible to type space or other delimiter and still type to get typeahead suggestions again? Basically I'm asking if there is a functionality to have typeahead suggestions for multiple possible values.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured there is no such functionality. I submitted a pull request to the maintainers of the ngx-bootstrap. Hopefully they will add it and everyone will have a possibility to use the new feature.